# Get the controller's return type in ExceptionFilterAttribute - HttpActionExecutedContext

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

If somewhere within the request lifecycle, an exception is thrown, the `HttpActionExecutedContext` has a `null` response.

```
public class MyExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{    
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext httpActionExecutedContext)
    {
        // Get expected return type here
        // Can't be httpActionExecutedContext.Response.GetType() because response is null
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is return the same expected object, but with an error created in one of the object's fields.

Is there a way to figure out what the expected response type is?

Comment: Is there a reason you need this? It's not always going to be possible.

Comment: Yes, the client is expecting an exact XML structure to be returned. Which means if the client is expecting AccountResponse, and an error occured, it would need to be without AccountResponse.Error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information you seek is within the provided context. You just have to go a little deeper to find it in the action descriptor.

```
public class MyExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute  
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext httpActionExecutedContext) {
        // Get expected return type here
        var expectedReturnType = httpActionExecutedContext.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor.ReturnType;

    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I was looking for!